# sub list of given positions

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider

```
r = Array[Total[{##}] &, {3, 3}]
(*{{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}*)
pos = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
```

This

```
r[[pos]]
```

gives the err

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression {{1,1},{2,2}} cannot be used as a part specification.
```

instead of the expected

```
{2,4}
```

In other words how to pick elements of a list at specific positions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`Apply (@@@)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) on `pos`:

```
r[[##]] & @@@ pos
```

> ```
>  {2, 4}
> ```

You can also use [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) or [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) or [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html):

```
Extract[pos] @ r
```

> ```
>  {2, 4}
> ```

```
Indexed[r, #] & /@ pos
```

> ```
>  {2, 4}
> ```

```
Query[##] @ r & @@@ pos
```

> ```
>  {2, 4}
> ```